# Фиолетовый экран Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Недавно обновил Ubuntu с 16.04 до 18.04 обновление прошло без ошибок, но после перезагрузки рабочий стол не появляется, стоит фиолетовый  экран и курсор. Я полный новичок в этом, можете подсказать как исправить? Ubuntu установлен на VMWare Workstation.

Comment: Ubuntu плохо справляется с обновлениями на более высокии версии. Либо драйвер видеокарты отвалится, либо конфликт с ядром. Лучше сидеть на одной версии, а если очень хочется на другую и нет опыта в этом, то - чистая установка.

Comment: От вновь созданного пользователя всё работает?

Comment: Возможно проблема с окружением. Попробуйте перейти в консоль и выполнить sudo apt-get dist-upgrade